# SQL Modeling (one to many) in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

I have a `product` table:

```
ProdId(PK)
Prod1
Prod2
Prod3 
Prod4
```

and `Certification` table:

```
Certification(PK):
Cert1
Cert2
Cert3
```

I need to model `ProdwithCert` relation (pseudo table) as follows:

```
ProdwithCertId(PK)              ProdwithCert
ProdwithCert1                   "Prod1 with Cert1"
ProdwithCert2                   "Prod1 with Cert1, Cert2"
ProdwithCert3                   "Prod1 with Cert1, Cert2, Cert3"
ProdwithCert4                   "Prod2 with Cert1, Cert2"
ProdwithCert5                   "Prod2 with Cert1, Cert2, Cert3"
```

**Following are the constraints:**

1. Cannot have duplicates, e.g. in above table, `ProdwithCert6 - "Prod2 with Cert1, Cert2, Cert3"` is not allowed
2. `Product` has at least one `Certification`

How do I properly model `ProdwithCert` relation in SQL Server 2005?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first requirement can be met by a `ProdwithCert` table with a primary key (or unique index) on `(ProductId, CertId)`.

The second requirement cannot be enforced using key or check constraints.  The only thing I can think of is to channel all modifications through a stored procedure.  The procedure could add a product with a certificate in one transaction.